# Searching for uniqueidentifier in CASE THEN-clause + wildcard

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I can't seem to find any information about this despite some serious searching. If I missed a previous post about this I'm sorry.

Anyway, I'm asking my db (sql server 2008) for a set where there's a uniqueidentifier as a parameter. However, if the input parameter is null, I want all to return all posts. I'll try to show it in code, perhaps it's easier to get the gist that way:

```
select * from ongoing_tbl_ongoing where ongoingState like
    case when @inParameter is null then 
        '%'              --This is where things go haywire
    else
        @inParameter     --This is a uniqueidentifier type (Guid)
    end
    or ongoingState is null
```

But this fails miserably (Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.)

Funny thing is this... the following code works:

```
select * from ongoing_tbl_ongoing where ongoingState like '%'
```

It seems the CASE-clause forces a cast or in some other way keeps me from doing wildcard searches on uniqueidentifiers. Any pointers would be highly appreciated. Please tell me if you want more information.

Best Regards
-K

Comment: what is the datatype of @inParameter

Comment: It's a uniqueidentifier, I'll edit the post. But the error is not on that line, the error is two lines above. The error occurs when @inParameter is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `'%'` and `@inParameter` must have the same data type. So you could cast the `@inParameter` to `VARCHAR`or use this query instead?

```
SELECT *
FROM ongoing_tbl_ongoing
WHERE ongoingState IS NULL OR
      @inParameter IS NULL OR
      ongoingState LIKE @inParameter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a case statement

```
select *    
from     
  ongoing_tbl_ongoing     
where     
  ongoingState is null     
or    
  ongoingState =    
    case when @inParameter is null then ongoingState
    else         @inParameter   
    end
```

Comment: Thanks man. This would be a great solution, but it will be very streamlined with my C#/xsd-integration. But on a pure sql-level it works great.